# Call Broadcast Receiver from another process

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, remote-process

In my application i have to use a BroadcastReceiver which must run in it's own process.

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.greenroad.mobile.asimov.tiles.AsimoveTileRequestUpdateReceiver"
        android:process="com.zonarsystems.Sample2020App.tile" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.zonarsystems.twenty20.tile.intent.action.TILE_REQUEST_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The application sending data to this receiver in order to process them.
for calling this receiver the application using

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.zonarsystems.twenty20.tile.intent.action.TILE_REQUEST_UPDATE");
    intent.putExtras(indicationsBundle);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

But i get nohing in

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { ... }
```

How it can be solved?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Comment: try `intent.putExtra("Msg","Testing");`. It's just `putExtra` not `putExtras`